# Wordpress - Alterações nos arquivos não são salvas no servidor

Tags: wordpress, servidor, ftp

Estou alterando site wordpress direto do FTP, os arquivos editados a princípio são salvos, mas alguns minutos depois as alterações feitas são modificadas para o código anterior. Isso tem a ver com permissão do arquivo?

Comment: alguns servidores demoram para atualizar os arquivos por definitivo quando utilizamos FTP, faça a alteração aguarde alguns minutos e veja se a alteração foi concluida.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly durante algum tempo são salvas, mas depois retorna o código como estava antes das alterações.

Comment: as alterações são em arquivos php? tem possibilidade de você estar alterando os arquivos do cache?

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida são arquivos .css e .php baixados do ftp

Comment: @scooby vc tem algum plugin de cache instalado? Em quais pastas estão os arquivos?

Comment: alguns plugins de segurança tb tem um esquema de bloquear alterações diretas em arquivos php

Comment: Às vezes o próprio hosting possui algum mecanismo de cache, como é o caso da Godaddy. Já tive muitos problemas por causa dele mas, não com arquivos css. De qualquer forma, verifique se há algum mecanismo de deploy específico no seu hosting ou forma de limpeza do cache.

Answer (score -1):

Isso já aconteceu comigo utilizando alguns plugins.
Quando eu editava alguma informação no wordpress, o plugin voltava a configuração original.
Eles fazem isso pois a alteração do mesmo, deve ser feito apenas pelo wordpress. Caso seja feita atualização do plugin, o mesmo continua funcionando com as alterações que você fez pelo wordpress, pois geralmente estão gravadas de forma específica no banco.